# sFlow configuration tcam question for Cisco Nexus 9396PX platform

Tags: cisco, network, sflow, tcam

I am trying to configure sflow on Nexus 9396PX switch and having some difficulty to understand tcam region.

```
hardware access-list tcam region span-sflow 256
!
feature sflow
sflow counter-poll-interval 30
sflow collector-ip 10.30.0.91 vrf management
sflow collector-port 9995
sflow agent-ip 172.30.0.26
```

when i enable on my `port-channel1` (which is 4x40G port bundle on GEM module)

```
sflow data-source interface port-channel1
```

When i run "show run sflow" to verify config i can't see "sflow data-source interface port-channel1" line there.

```
N9K(config)# show run sflow

!Command: show running-config sflow
!Running configuration last done at: Tue Apr 13 14:24:00 2021
!Time: Tue Apr 13 14:24:58 2021

version 9.3(6) Bios:version 07.68
feature sflow

sflow counter-poll-interval 30
sflow collector-ip 10.30.0.91 vrf management
sflow collector-port 9995
sflow agent-ip 172.30.0.26
```

For experiment i tried to add `Ethernet 1/1`  (10G port) and that works i can see that in "show run" Look like 40G Gem module doesn't supported. so i did google and found this on Cisco website

> Make sure that the sFlow and SPAN ACL TCAM region sizes are configured
> for any uplink ports that are to be configured as an sFlow data source
> on the following devices: Cisco Nexus 9332PQ, 9372PX, 9372TX, and
> 93120TX switches and Cisco Nexus 9396PX, 9396TX, and 93128TX switches
> with the N9K-M6PQ or N9K-M12PQ generic expansion module (GEM).

Question, is what is SPAN ACL region all i can see following on my switch, does SPAN ACL is ing-
l2-span-filter or ing-l3-span-filter ?

```
hardware access-list tcam region span 0
hardware access-list tcam region ing-l2-span-filter 0
hardware access-list tcam region ing-l3-span-filter 0
hardware access-list tcam region ipv6-span-udf 0
hardware access-list tcam region ipv6-span-l2-udf 0
hardware access-list tcam region span-sflow 256
```

Comment: Not sure about the Nexus, but on many platform you can collect sFlow samples only on physical ports.

Comment: I have tried physical 40G port also but doesn't work, Cisco document saying you can configure `Port-Channel` for sFlow source interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the solution, we need both `span` and `sflow` tcam size 256, so i took `vPC` slice and give it to `span` region (**Notes:** following solution only apply for 40G Interface, if you are using 10G for data-source then nothing to do)

```
hardware access-list tcam region vpc-convergence 0
hardware access-list tcam region sflow 256
hardware access-list tcam region span 256
```

Now i am able to use Port-Channel (4x40G bundle)

```
feature sflow

sflow counter-poll-interval 30
sflow collector-ip 172.29.0.91 vrf management
sflow collector-port 9995
sflow agent-ip 172.29.0.236

sflow data-source interface port-channel1
```

sflow stats

```
N9K# show sflow
sflow sampling-rate : 4096
sflow max-sampled-size : 128
sflow counter-poll-interval : 30
sflow max-datagram-size : 1400
sflow collector-ip : 172.29.0.91 , vrf : management
sflow collector-port : 9995
sflow agent-ip : 172.29.0.236
sflow data-source interface port-channel1

N9K# show sflow statistics
Total Packets        : 4921
Total Samples        : 0
Processed Samples    : 0
Dropped Samples      : 0
Sent Datagrams       : 39
Dropped Datagrams    : 0
```